Is it safe to move scaffolded Identity pages from Areas\Identity\Pages to main site's Pages?
I have a Razor website built with ASP.NET Core 8 and the Identity framework. I have scaffolded the Identity pages, and they seem to work fine. But I don't like their paths - "/Identity/Account/Manage/something". I am considering moving the "Areas\Identity\Pages\Accounts" files into the Pages\profile directory and updating the internal links so that a user would see just a "/profile/manage/something" path. I have not found information about anyone doing this.
My concern is that, possibly, some paths come from the outside of the pages (like from the framework itself) or are derived in some obscure way (e.g., from the namespace name).
I understand that I can add custom (additional) routes, but this approach would keep the main links long.
So, the question is - does anybody have experience with moving those scaffolded pages around? What else should I update besides the links inside the pages?

If it's only don't like their paths, then I'm afraid we'd better not to change it as it doesn't bring much benefit but it might bring potenial risks....
